# Is there a better way to write Private messages in Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've got a service request message object that can be private, which means that it's only visible to user who created the service request and the person who wrote the message.  The code below works, but is messy.  Is there a better way to do that that's a little cleaner/dryer?

```
<% m = @message %>
<% if m.private == true %>
    <% if m.user_id == current_user.id || @service_request.user_id == current_user.id %>
      <div class="jumbotron">
        <%= render 'service_request_messages', service_request_message: m %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  <% else %>
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <%= render 'service_request_messages', service_request_message: m %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Would like to keep it DRY

Answer (score 0):

```
<% if !m.private || current_user.id.in?([m.user_id, @service_request.user_id]) %>
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <%= render 'service_request_messages', service_request_message: m %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

If `private` is column name, probably it's bad idea to use it

For example inside model you can't easily access `private` attribute because it is reserved Ruby word

It's better to use something like `published` column instead

I suggest such variant

```
<% if m.published? || m.owner?(current_user) || @service_request.owner?(current_user) %>
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <%= render 'service_request_messages', service_request_message: m %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

You just need define these methods inside corresponding entities to compare user ids